# Call-Site Code Replacement in Functional Programming Languages

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I just wonder whether it is possible in a functional
language to do call site replacement. I envision this
as a special form of lazyness.

Basically I would call somewhere a function f
with an argument a:

```
... (f a) ...
```

The function would then manage to replace itself
by a function g with an argument b:

```
... (g b) ...
```

So that the next time the original call site of (f a)
is invoked in fact (g b) is invoked.

Hints welcome.

Bye

P.S.: Its for Just-In-Time (JIT) compilation.
Polymorphic inline caches and the like.
See for example:

**Optimizing Dynamically - Typed Object - Oriented

Languages with Polymorphic Inline Caches**
Urs Hölzle, Craig Chambers, David Ungar
ECOOP '91 Proceedings of the European
Conference on Object-Oriented Programming
http://selflanguage.org/_static/published/pics.pdf

Comment: I think providing a little more context will mean the answers can be better. :)

Answer (score 12):

That's basically the automaton arrow:

```
newtype Auto a b = Auto (a -> (b, Auto a b))
```

In Haskell it's not possible for a function to replace itself, but the automaton arrow represents functions that return a new version of themselves along with a result:

```
switcher :: Bool -> Auto Bool Bool
switcher x =
    Auto $ \y ->
        (x, switcher $ if y then not x else x)
```

The useful thing about the automaton arrow is that it is, well, an arrow, so the `Category` instance allows you to compose such functions.  There is also a very useful applicative instance.

Side note:  This is the basis of arrowized functional reactive programming (AFRP).

Comment: Do you think when a loop is implemented as a fixpoint, this could lead to ever improving call-sites? Can I use an ordinary fixpoint or do I need a special fixpoint?

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, you can provide custom optimization rewritings via the RULES pragma.
See [the GHC user guide > Rewrite Rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html) for details.

Comment: How can I control that these rules are applied during runtime when f decides so?

Comment: Rewrite rules are a compile time optimization. If you want "substitution" to happen at runtime, then just write the definition for `f` as `f a = g b`

Comment: If I would be able to specify a dynamic inlining strategy, yes.